# Scala - writing a non-generic tree. Issue with type parameters

Tags: scala, generics, tree, variance

I am having a mindblank with Scala generics and variance, and I can't understand some things.

Here is what I have so far:

```
sealed abstract class Tree[+T]
case class Node[+T](value: T, left: Tree[T], right: Tree[T]) extends Tree[T] {
  override def toString = "T(" + value.toString + " " + left.toString + " " + right.toString + ")"
}
case object End extends Tree[Nothing] {
  override def toString = "."
}
object Node {
  def apply[T](value: T): Node[T] = Node(value, End, End)
}
```

A basic genericed binary tree. What I want to do, is specialize it so that `T` is a subtype of some class say `Rectangle`. The reason I want to do this, is to create an `addValue` method that uses some methods of `Rectangle` (I.e. it's a tree using some stuff in `Rectangle`):

```
sealed abstract class Tree[+T] {
  def addValue
}
```

I know I could define `Ordering` on rectangle and do this:

```
sealed abstract class Tree[+T] {
  def addValue[U >: T <% Ordered[U]](x: U): Tree[U]
}
```

But I feel there is an easier way to constrain `T` to be a subtype of `Rectangle`.

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is, you like to solve with a non-generic type. You only show an example which can be solved and provide the solution yourself.

Answer (score 1):

To restrict the generic type `T` to be a subtype of `Rectangle`, you use the `<:` operator:

```
class Rectangle
class GenericThing[T <: Rectangle](x: T)

new GenericThing(new Rectangle) // fine
new GenericThing(5) // inferred type arguments [Int] do not conform to class GenericThing's type parameter bounds [T <: Rectangle]
```